# Float number formatting issue

Tags: c#, string-formatting, tostring

i've noticed a rounding issue that occurs when i format a value to currency -- the decimal value changes once i pass a certain thershold.

here are 3 samples - the first one succeeds but the other 2 don't as the initial value is increased.

1)

```
float value = 10000.25;

value_as_string = value .ToString( "0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

--> "10000.25";  // great
```

2)

```
float value = 100000.25;

value_as_string = value .ToString( "0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

--> "100,000.20"  // why 20 cents?
```

3)

```
float value = 1000000.25;

value_as_string = value .ToString( "0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

--> "1,000,000.00"  // where did my 25 cents go?
```

please let me know if there's a work around to this.  thanks.

Comment: In your 3rd example, I'd be more concerned about how 100,000 turned into 1,000,000. That aside, it looks like a has to do with significant figures. All results look as if they're configured to have 7 sigfigs.

Comment: which programming language are we discussing here?

Comment: Guessing... This looks like it might be C#?

Comment: sorry about that - the 3rd example had a typo. the value going in should've been 1000000.00.  i'm using C#.

Comment: Float only has 7 significant digits, double only 15, apart from other issues. Don't use floating point numbers to represent money. Use `decimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose precision because of the `float` value type. Use the `decimal` type:

```
decimal valueDec = 1000000.25M;

string valueDec_string = valueDec.ToString("0,0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Output:

> 1,000,000.25